# Heroku Yarn Deployment Issue: Double Resolving packages

Tags: node.js, heroku, yarnpkg

I'm trying to set up our first Heroku project, but I'm having trouble getting the deployment to work. It always fails during Package install. What's interesting is that in the log I can see it attempting to install packages twice and I think running it twice is causing the issue seen here:

```
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  ^10.16
       engines.npm (package.json):   ^6.9
       engines.yarn (package.json):  ^1.17

       Resolving node version ^10.16...
       Downloading and installing node 10.16.3...
       Bootstrapping npm ^6.9 (replacing 6.9.0)...
       npm ^6.9 installed
       Resolving yarn version ^1.17...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.19.1)...
       Installed yarn 1.19.1

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.19.1
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       warning package.json: No license field
       warning nest-console@5.7.3: No license field
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/external-editor/-/external-editor-1.1.1.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/tmp/yarncache.BXSXb/v6/npm-external-editor-1.1.1-12d7b0db850f7ff7e7081baf4005700060c4600b-integrity/node_modules/external-editor/example_async.js'"
       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
-----> Build failed
```

Every time it runs, it fails on a different file but with the same error.

I'm using the NodeJS buildpack. I'm at a complete loss. I feel like I'd be able to further diagnose what was happening if I could see the actual commands being run.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before?

Comment: Having run into this exact issue, forking the node-js buildpack then adding `--network-concurrency 1` to the `yarn install` in `dependencies.sh` fixed it, but I don't think thats exactly a great answer, so I'm leaving it as a comment, and hoping someone better than me has a better idea.

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the yarn.lock - it did the trick for me :)